# backbone-js: how can I silently initialize a new Collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I must be doing something dumb, or maybe missing some crucial part of the Backbone documentation, but I cant understand why the Model.validate function is firing when I initialize a new Collection in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/5a3k/QSeH6/  ..any ideas where I'm going wrong?

edit: changed title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By executing this line:

```
var myCollection = new Collection([{id: 'smith'}]);
```

You create new collection with one model. All models passed in the constructor will be added into the collection. Each added model is validated.

Details:

1. Backbone.Collection constructor is calling `this.reset()` ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-54)).
2. `.reset()` will silently add all the models into the collection ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-66)).
3. `.add()` will call internal `._add()` for each model ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-59)).
4. Internal `._add()` will call `.prepareModel` which is checking if the model is valid ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-72)).

**Update** (based on edit in the question):

`model.validate` is executed only if the model  is not instance of `Backbone.Model` ([source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-72)).

So if you create a collection using

```
var myCollection = new Collection([{id: 'smith'}]);
```

then the model is instance of `Object`. But if you use:

```
var myCollection = new Collection([ new Model({id: 'smith'}) ]);
```

then the model is instance of `Backbone.Model` and validation is skipped.

Comment: yes thats what I thought, so I do `myCollection.reset([{id: 'smith'}]);` - http://jsfiddle.net/5a3k/QSeH6/17/   ..but validate still fires..

Comment: @zack: See details in the answer. Constructor is calling `.reset()` which is adding and validating the model. If you call `.reset()` yourself then you are also triggering the validation - only 1st step in the details list is skipped.